# Axapta and the great White Space Robbery

Tags: whitespace, axapta

Along a similiar vein to [this question](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Axapta-Programming/36065705/only-spaces-in-string-field.aspx), I'd like to store only white space in an Ax2009 table field.

> ...We want to be able to store " " (string containing one space or more) in a field (the field content is exported to a plain text file later on).
>
> After an insert, the value remains " ", but if we do a Select on the table the value is replaced by "".

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but trailing spaces are removed.
Live with it.

Comment: Thanks Jan.  I can confirm that white space is removed from the right, but not from the left in these string type fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the workaround used in standard AX for field `AddressFormatLines.Separator`

An additional field `NumOfSpaces` is used to overcome this AX limitation, methods `insert`, `update`, and `postLoad` are overridden accordingly, and as a result you can store a white space and also see it in forms (although you won't see it in SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

there is actually a way of storing a white space at the end of a string field. Instead of using the normal space bar enter Alt+255. That will create a space which is not removed.

Comment: This would be a great suggestion if it was for a report to printed to screen or paper but the fields are being written to a file and FTP'd to an external system.  I don't know how that system treats the Alt+255 character....  I could perform a strReplace before sending it of course.

Comment: But then padding the field on output would be easier. A single Alt+255 is equal to naStr().